# if $T$ is a bijection then $T$ is a topological isomorphism.

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $X,Y$ are Banach spaces.$D$ is a subspace of $X$ and $T:D \rightarrow Y$ is a closed linear mapping.Prove that:if $T$ is a bijection then $T$ is a topological isomorphism.

I proved if T is a surjection then $T$ is a open mapping.So,$T^{-1}$ is continuous.Now,i need to prove that T is continuous.I proved $T$ is continuous if and only if $D$ is close in $X$.But I don't know why $D$ is close.

Comment: Is $D$ a closed subspace?

Comment: @Andres: I need this to finish my proof

Comment: I would say more than that. Even your first sentence requires that $D$ be a Banach space to invoke the open mapping theorem, which occurs if and only if its a closed subspace.

Comment: My first sentence looks like the open mapping theorem but it doesn't. I proved it without using the open mapping theorem.

Comment: By "closed linear mapping", do you mean that the graph is closed, or that it maps closed subsets (of $D$) to closed subsets (of $Y$)?

Comment: @Daniel:The graph is closed

Comment: The assertion doesn't follow unless one adds closedness of $D$ to the premises. Consider $X = \ell^2(\mathbb{N}),\, Y = \ell^1(\mathbb{N})$, $\iota \colon Y \to X$ the natural inclusion, $D = \iota(Y)$ and $T = \iota^{-1}$. If $T$ were a topological isomorphism, the $\ell^1$-norm and $\ell^2$-norm on $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ would be equivalent [and that incidentally would imply $\ell^1(\mathbb{N}) = \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ as sets]. But they aren't. Yet $T$ is a closed (actually in both senses) linear bijection between $D$ and $Y$.

Comment: What does $l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$ mean?

Comment: @Daniel:$l^{2} \subset l^{1}$

Comment: No, the sequence $x$ with $x_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$ belongs to $\ell^2$, but not to $\ell^1$.

Comment: what does $l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$ mean?

Comment: Generally, for a set $S$ and $1 \leqslant p < \infty$, $$\ell^p(S) := \left\{ f \colon S \to \mathbb{C} : \sum_{s \in S} \lvert f(s)\rvert^p < +\infty \right\}.$$ So $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ is the space of $p$-summable sequences (indexed by $\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: @Daniel: if $T$ were a topological isomorphism, the $l^{1}$-norm and $l^{2}$-norm on $l^{1}(\mathbb{N})$  would be equivalent but why does this imply $l^{1}(\mathbb{N})=l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$ as sets?

Comment: Because for $1 \leqslant p < \infty$, $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ is the completion of the space of sequences with only finitely many nonzero terms with respect to the $\ell^p$-norm. If two norms on a space $X$ are equivalent, its completion with respect to one "is" the completion with respect to the other too. Or: $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ is complete with respect to the $\ell^1$-norm, if the two norms were equivalent, it would be complete with respect to the $\ell^2$-norm too, hence a closed subspace of $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. Since it's dense, it must be the whole space then.

Comment: @Daniel: Do you take an example to prove that $l^{1}(\mathbb{N})$ is not  complete with respect to the $l^{2}$-norm ?

Comment: Take an $x \in \ell^2(\mathbb{N}) \setminus \ell^1(\mathbb{N})$, and let $x_n$ be the sequence agreeing with $x$ in the first $n$ coordinates, and being $0$ afterwards. Then $(x_n)$ is an $\ell^2$ Cauchy sequence that doesn't converge in $\ell^1$.

Comment: How wonderful! Thanks.